# std::string variable doesn't keep its value

Tags: c++, string, oop

So I have std::list of a class and I add objects of its derived classes(e.g. "Discus" is a derived class of "Item"). I have several `std::string` variables and I initialize it in constructor. That `std::string` variables are gotten via `std::cin`, I put such variables right into a constructor. E.g. 'name' and 'material', that's gotten via `std::cin`, it's just `std::string`. So it has some values. But when I go out of that function, its values are empty(it's like ""). What can cause this problem? I suppose that 'name' and 'material' variables are being deleted, but I'm not sure if it's true and how to get rid of this problem. 
Sorry if this question is kinda silly, thanks for any help.

```
class Discus : public Throwable, public Material {
public:
    Discus(int, int, int, std::string*, std::string*);
    void setMaterial(std::string*);
    void setType();
    std::string info();
};

class Storage {
private:
    std::list<Item*> storage;
public:
    std::list<Item*>* getStorage();
    void addItem(Item*);
    void showInfo();
};
```

That's the implementation of a function I use to add Items:

```
void addItem(Storage* store) {
bool to_continue = true;
while (to_continue) {
    std::cout << "What to add?\n1)Discus\n2)Javelin\n3)Hammer\n4)Dumbbell\n5)Kettlebell\n6)Barbell\0 для to exit\n";
    int key = -1;
    std::cin >> key;
    if (key > 0 && key < 7) {
        int parameters[3];
        std::cout << "Enter price, amount of items, the weight of an item\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) std::cin >> parameters[i];
        std::string name;
        std::string material;
        int len = 0;
        std::cout << "Enter name:\n";
        std::cin >> name;
        switch (key) {
        case 1: {
            std::cout << "Enter a name of material:\n";
            std::cin >> material;
            Discus d(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], &material, &name);
            Discus* it = &d;
            (*store).addItem(it);
            break;  
        }
        case 2: {
            std::cout << "Enter a name of material:\n";
            std::cin >> material;
            std::cout << "Enter a length:\n";
            std::cin >> len;
            (*store).getStorage()->push_back(&Javelin(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], &material, len, &name));
            break; 
        }
        case 3: {
            std::cout << "Enter a name of material:\n";
            std::cin >> material;
            std::cout << "Enter a length:\n";
            std::cin >> len;
            (*store).getStorage()->push_back(&Hammer(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], &material, len, &name));
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {(*store).getStorage()->push_back(&Dumbbell(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], &name)); break; }
        case 5: {
            std::cout << "Enter a name of material:\n";
            std::cin >> material;
            (*store).getStorage()->push_back(&Kettlebell(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], &material, &name));
            break;
        }
        case 6: {
            std::cout << "Enter a length:\n";
            std::cin >> len;
            (*store).getStorage()->push_back(&Barbell(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], len, &name));
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    else if (key == 0) 
        to_continue = false;
    else std::cout << "Sorry, try one more time\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use pointers? What is your requirement?

Comment: Also, Please give more info on the part of code in which object `d` is created.

Comment: `void setMaterial(std::string*);` its strange to use `std::string*`

Comment: `&d` is an invalid pointer as soon as `d`’s lifetime ends. (There are far too many pointers in this code. Consider thinking it over a few more times.)

Comment: added function that add Items.

Comment: @molbdnilo is correct. There should be a few duplicates for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: Note that all of the `(*store).getStorage()->push_back(&Javelin ...` and similar calls are wrong as well for the same reason (you are taking the address of a temporary). My advice is to not use pointers for any of this.

Comment: I think one must never use raw pointers unless there is necessity to do so. One should always look for smart pointers. If they don't suffice, then one should think twice before using raw pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason behind this is that the object might be dying when it is going out of scope.

It seems your situation is somewhat like this:

```
...
    if (key > 0 && key < 7) {
        ...
        std::string name;
        std::string material;
        ...
        switch (key) {
        case 1: {
            ...
            Discus d(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], &material, &name);
            Discus* it = &d;
            (*store).addItem(it);
            break;  
        } // d will die here. So, pointer it will become dangling
    } // name and material will die here. So, pointers to them will become dangling.
```

You may consider using `const std::string &` for your purpose instead of `std::string *`. For object of class `Discus`, instead of using *raw* pointer, you may go for `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Well, I was suppose that something similar happened. Thanks for explanation

Comment: @PaulSnopov If you feel that this answered your question, please consider it for upvote and acceptance.